# Allowing multiple selections for Scala functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have a scala function that selects documents based on the year, i.e.

```
def keepDate(date: String, component: DateComponent = DateComponent.YYYYMMDD) = {
   rdd.filter(r => ExtractDate(r.getCrawlDate, component) == date)
}
```

It is used in the code like so, which works:

```
.keepDate("2007", YYYY)
```

However, what we would like to do is allow multiple matching - i.e. some variation of:

```
.keepDate("2007", "2010", YYYY)
```

So far my attempts to do this have failed. The exact syntax that we use doesn't matter, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What attempts... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def keepDate(dates: List[String], component: DateComponent = DateComponent.YYYYMMDD) = {
  rdd.filter(r => dates.contains(ExtractDate(r.getCrawlDate, component)))
}
```

Now you can use it like this,

```
.keepDate(List("2007", "2010"), YYYY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple parameter lists would be the way I'd do it:

```
def keepDate(component: DateComponent = DateComponent.YYYYMMDD)(dates: String*) = {
  rdd.filter(r => dates.contains(r => ExtractDate(r.getCrawlDate, component)))   
}
```

And using it is like this:

```
keepDate(YYYY)("2010", "2012)
```

If the number of dates gets sufficiently large, consider using a `Set[String]` instead of varargs (which would be a bit more verbose, but more efficient).